# jQuery Sliding door effect in FancyBox image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, portfolio

How do you make the FancyBox jQuery images clickable with the Sliding Door Hover Effect in a portfolio gallery? Right now the sliding door effect works **BUT** the fancybox doesn't do anything when you click on the gallery image.

How can I get **both** jquery.easing.1.3.js (sliding door effect) and jquery.fancybox.js to work together?

I followed the instructions in the comments for this [tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/620/create-a-stunning-sliding-door-effect-with-jquery) to **DELETE**: window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');   - in the jquery.easing HTML Head Tag code

My website has a lot going on because it's a one-page portfolio. I'm trying to finish this website to send to employers for jobs. I'm frustrated because I've been working on this website for so LONG and I need a job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the

```
window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

with

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
$.fancybox({
    'padding'       : 0,
    'href'          : url,
    'title'         : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'type'      : 'image'
});
```

**Note that**

I am using `'type' : 'image'` because I am loading images from links like `http://placekitten.com/200/300`, in such cases forcing type is necessary as the `url` doesn't have a valid image extension .

Remove that if you dont need that.

[Working Demo](http://joynag.net/demos/door/)

Comment: YOU ROCK! Thank you so much! I'm going to try it now!

Comment: FIXED! I'm so happy I can dance now! ~Does Fresh Prince Carlton Dance~

Comment: If this solved your problem, please go ahead and accept the answer. I am glad to be able to help. :)